# How can I save multiple form outputs (forms are on diffrent pages, biut shows in one iframe) in one preview page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, iframe

I have 2 separate forms that displays in one iframe, I want users to enter data in input, click on next button then enter input of form 2, click on a review button, then show form 1 and form 2 output in one preview page before submitting the data to a database. I have tried session storage but I know that my code is wrong.

```
var formValues = [];
SessionStorage.setItem("fname", "fname");
SessionStorage.setItem("lname", "lname");
SessionStorage.setItem("phone-field", "phone-field");
SessionStorage.setItem("email-field", "email-field");

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".next").click(fuction() {
    $("#fname").val("fname");
    $("#lname").val("lname");
    $("#phone-field").val("phone-field");
    $("#email-field").val("email-field");


var formValues = sessionStorage.getItem("fname");
console.log(formValues);

$(document).ready(function() {

                $('.next').click(function() {
                  var formValues = [];
                  // get values from inputs in first fieldset
                  $('.field1 :input').each(function() {
                    formValues.push($(this).val());
                  });

                  formValues.pop(); //remove the button from input values
                  console.log(formValues);

                // set values in second fieldset
                  $('.field3 :input').each(function(index) {
                    if (formValues[index]) {
                      $(this).val(formValues[index]);
                    }
                  });

                  $('.current').removeClass('current').hide().next().show().addClass('current');

                });

                $('.previous').click(function() {
                  $('.current').removeClass('current').hide().prev().show().addClass('current');

                });
              });   

                   $(document).ready(function() {

                $('.review').click(function() {
                  var formValues = [];
                  // get values from inputs in first fieldset
                  $('.field2 :input').each(function() {
                    formValues.push($(this).val());
                  });

                  formValues.pop(); //remove the button from input values
                  console.log(formValues);

                  // set values in second fieldset
                  $('.field3 :input').each(function(index) {
                    if (formValues[index]) {
                      $(this).val(formValues[index]);
                    }
                  });

                  $('.current').removeClass('current').hide().next().show().addClass('current');

                });

                $('.previous').click(function() {
                  $('.current').removeClass('current').hide().prev().show().addClass('current');

                });
              });
```

FORM 1

```
<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@4.0.5" data-semver="4.0.5" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="bootstrap@4.0.5" data-semver="4.0.5" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="jquery@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="helpdeskform" action="process.php" method="post">
    <fieldset class="field1 current">
      <h2>Form</h2>
      <p>
        <label class="form-label first-name" for="fname">First Name:</label>
        <input name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" type="text" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label class="form-label last-name" for="lname">Last Name:</label>
        <input name="lname" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name" type="text" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label class="form-label" for="phone-field">Phone:</label>
        <input name="phone" id="phone-field" placeholder="Phone Number" type="text" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label class="form-label" for="email-field">E-mail:</label>
        <input name="email" id="email-field" placeholder="E-mail" type="text" />
      </p>
      <hr />
      <label for="review">
        <input onclick="location.href='index3.html'" id="next" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" type="button" />
      </label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="field3">

      <p>First Name:
        <input class="show_fname" readonly="readonly" type="text" />
      </p>
      <p>Last Name:
        <input class="show_lname" readonly="readonly" type="text" />
      </p>
      <p>Type of Request:
        <input class="show_type_of_request" readonly="readonly" type="text" />
      </p>
      <p>Short Description:
        <input class="show_subject" readonly="readonly" type="text" />
      </p>
      <p>Additional Comments:
        <input class="show_comments" readonly="readonly" type="text" />
      </p>
      <p style="float:left;">
        <label for="previous">
          <input name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" type="button" />
        </label>
      </p>
      <p style="float:left; padding-left: 10px;">
        <label for="Submit">
          <input value="Submit" name="submit" class="action-button" type="submit" />
        </label>
      </p>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

fORM 2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@4.0.5" data-semver="4.0.5" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="bootstrap@4.0.5" data-semver="4.0.5" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="jquery@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="helpdeskform" action="process.php" method="post">
    <fieldset class="field2 current">
      <h2>Form 2</h2>
      <label for="classify">Type of Request:</label>
      <select name="classify" id="classify">
        <option value="">Please select an option..</option>
        <option value="maintainence">Maintainence of Site</option>
        <option value="troubleshoot">Troubleshoot/Error</option>
        <option value="new">Create new content</option>
      </select>
      <p></p>
      <p>
        <label for="subject">Short Description: <span class="counter-field">
              <span id="counter"></span> characters left.</span>
        </label>
        <input name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" type="text" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="desc">Additional Comments:</label>
        <textarea style="font-family: Arial, Veranda, Sans serif" name="desc" id="desc" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Short Description"></textarea>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="review">
          <input name="review" onclick="showData();" class="review action-button" value="Review" type="button" />
        </label>
      </p>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="field3">
      <!-- @TODO PREVIEW ALL FORM INPUTS -->
      <p>First Name:
        <input class="show_fname" readonly="readonly" type="text" />
      </p>
      <p>Last Name:
        <input class="show_lname" readonly="readonly" type="text" />
      </p>
      <p>Phone:
        <input class="show_phone" readonly="readonly" type="text" />
      </p>
      <p>E-mail:
        <input class="show_email" readonly="readonly" type="text" />
      </p>
      <p>Type of Request:
        <input class="show_type_of_request" readonly="readonly" type="text" />
      </p>
      <p>Short Description:
        <input class="show_subject" readonly="readonly" type="text" />
      </p>
      <p>Additional Comments:
        <input class="show_comments" readonly="readonly" type="text" />
      </p>
      <p style="float:left;">
        <label for="previous">
          <input name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" type="button" />
        </label>
      </p>
      <p style="float:left; padding-left: 10px;">
        <label for="Submit">
          <input value="Submit" name="submit" class="action-button" type="submit" />
        </label>
      </p>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Only the form 2 values are shown on the preview page. I only posted form 1 code, do you want form 2 code?

Comment: I want form 1 and form 2 to show in a preview page, but only form 2 values show on the preview page

Comment: I don't want anything. Stackoverflow recommends you post a [mcve].